# R package NAMESPACE: Packages listed in more than one category

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I'm trying to make an R package out of some functions that I use frequently. However, when I build the package and run `check`, I get the NOTE:

```
Packages listed in more of one Depends, Imports, Suggests, Enhances: dplyr, ggplot2, network
```

I find this curious because I only use the Depends field in my DESCRIPTION file, I don't even use the other fields. I also use more packages than these three but apparently, the issue only comes up with these three packages. I can still use my package but I'd like to understand how this issue emerges and fix it if possible.

**EDIT for clarity**

These are the Depends from my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Depends: stringi, stringr, qdapRegex, readr, tokenizers, rvest, pryr, XML, xml2, lubridate, data.table, ggplot2, anytime, dplyr, network, quanteda, ggmap, networkDynamic, mgsub, dplyr, ggplot2, network, stats, ndtv
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.0
```

These are the importsFrom in my NAMESPACE file:

```
import(ggplot2)
import(quanteda)
importFrom(XML,xmlToList)
importFrom(XML,xmlTreeParse)
importFrom(anytime,anytime)
importFrom(data.table,":=")
importFrom(data.table,.I)
importFrom(data.table,.N)
importFrom(data.table,data.table)
importFrom(data.table,rleid)
importFrom(dplyr,"%>%")
importFrom(dplyr,group_by)
importFrom(dplyr,n)
importFrom(dplyr,summarise)
importFrom(ggmap,get_map)
importFrom(ggmap,ggmap)
importFrom(lubridate,parse_date_time)
importFrom(mgsub,mgsub)
importFrom(ndtv,compute.animation)
importFrom(ndtv,render.d3movie)
importFrom(network,get.edge.attribute)
importFrom(network,get.vertex.attribute)
importFrom(network,set.edge.attribute)
importFrom(network,set.vertex.attribute)
importFrom(networkDynamic,networkDynamic)
importFrom(pryr,bytes)
importFrom(qdapRegex,ex_emoticon)
importFrom(qdapRegex,rm_between)
importFrom(qdapRegex,rm_default)
importFrom(qdapRegex,rm_url)
importFrom(quanteda,dfm_group)
importFrom(quanteda,stopwords)
importFrom(quanteda,textplot_wordcloud)
importFrom(readr,parse_character)
importFrom(rvest,html_nodes)
importFrom(stats,runif)
importFrom(stringi,stri_extract_all_regex)
importFrom(stringi,stri_split_fixed)
importFrom(stringi,stri_split_regex)
importFrom(stringr,str_extract_all)
importFrom(stringr,str_replace_all)
importFrom(tokenizers,tokenize_words)
importFrom(utils,read.csv)
importFrom(xml2,read_html)
```

Comment: Does your NAMESPACE file include `importsfrom` entries from any of these packages?

Comment: @AllanCameron it might! Could that be the issue? I'll check tomorrow!